# Why JQuery load doesn't send my variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got some code, which works fine, but I wanted to change it a little and the small problem has arisen.

```
    <button data-toggle='modal' data-target="#myModal" class='myClass' id='133'>Click me</button>

    $('.myClass').on('click', function(e){
        var idSend = $(this).attr('id');
        e.preventDefault();
    
    $('#myDiv').load( "action.php?action=doSomething", { id: idSend }, function() {
        alert(idSend);
    });
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

On the `action.php` page I make `print_r($_POST);` and my variable is there. Now I wanted to use data-id instead of id attribute:

```
<button data-toggle='modal' data-target="#myModal" class='myClass' data-id='133'>Click me</button>

$('.myClass').on('click', function(e){
         var idSend = $(this).data('id');
         e.preventDefault();
    
          $('#myDiv').load( "action.php?action=doSomething", { id: idSend }, function() {
              alert(idSend);
          });
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

Function `alert(idSend)` shows my id number fine, but on the action.php page $_POST is empty. Can you please explain me this issue?

Comment: or $.post instead of .load

Comment: $_GET in these cases is showing me only my action => doSomething variable

Comment: I can see the data in `$_POST` fine when I test it locally.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin, so I checked once and I found something interesting, but I still don't know why is that happening, I will edit my post

Comment: Ohhhh I'm so stupid, I found my issue, I will write answer and close topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot, that my page is refreshing some content every 15 seconds. Thanks to @Quentin I realized that after one refreshing my second solution was working like first. After that I found, that I have my first solution code duplicated in part of page, which was not being refreshed. So my second solution was being overwritten by my first idea, but after refreshing it my second solution overwrote it and start to work again. Unfortunately in my  duplicated code there was no `alert` yet, so I didn't know that it was happening.

Ugh... so my messy code and sclerosis was the answer.